# Resharper wont refactor similar block when extracting method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

In some unittest I want to refactor some block of code that is duplicate.

So I select a block of code for example the one below:

```
var timer = Substitute.For<ITimer>();
var alertSender = Substitute.For<IAlertSender>();
var alert = new Alert(NotificationType.Clear, new AlertConfiguration("test", 1, new List<string>()), timer, alertSender);
```

Unfortunately when resharper does create the method for me it does not detect identical block of code and refactor it for me as well.
Is there any remedy to this issue?

Comment: it is the exact same block of code.

Comment: I don't think ReSharper is that smart. You must understand that every tool has its own limitations.

Comment: @LexLi That is just a matter of doing pattern matching on the AST. Some smalltalk tool has this feature for ages.

Comment: The difficulty of a feature is not the only measure the product manager uses to say when it should be included in a product. Obviously ReSharper has many other features to implement and rather leave this to external plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't do this out of the box, as @citizenmatt mentioned. However, there's a plugin for ReSharper called [Agent Ralph](https://github.com/jbuedel/AgentRalphPlugin) that supposedly handles refactoring duplicated code blocks!

You can install it from the [ReSharper Gallery](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AgentRalph/) if you have ReSharper 8 (it seems the plugin wasn't updated to use v8.2 yet, however).

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper doesn't do this, but there's an issue open, please feel free to vote for it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-274811